# View variable values without any breakpoints in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

In Eclipse with Android, is it possible to run an app in debug mode but not have any breakpoints but still view the value of variables as they get updated?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add a `watchpoint` instead of a `breakpoint`. But still the debugger will stop on the watch point every time the variable you are watching is read or modified

Comment: I don't want the code to stop. I just want to view the variable while it is running.